# XMLHttpRequest halts server response until ajax completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, html5-canvas

I have the following ajax code that sends a canvas (aprox. 350kb) to a server for processing:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST",'www.domain.com/process.php',true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
    }
});
```

The problem is that when the ajax call is executed we can not access any other page on the server www.domain.com. It keeps on waiting until the called is completed.

Am I doing something wrong here or does it just not suitable for the task we need to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: can you actually start a url with "www" ?

Comment: if even a page in another browser stalls, it sounds like your server sucks, not the client JS. you might want to consider node.js to catch the uploads: it can handle more than one thing at a time...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing proper quotes around the argument of `ajax.open` API.

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST",'www.domain.com/process.php',true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, you are right. that was just a typo when copying the code here. still, the initial question remains open...